# Calculate the Time an Incident Took to Resolve in Microsoft Dynamics CRM in Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I am creating a report for Dynamics CRM cases. I want to calculate the time spent to resolve a case.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use difference between createdon and modifiedon fields of incident record.

Comment: This would only work if a case was never modified after it was resolved.

Comment: If case was resolved it is put to readonly state so modifiedon field would not be changed. Correct me if I wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the date difference between the Case creation date (*field `createdon` on entity **`incident`***) and the related Case Resolution record's creation date (*field `createdon` on entity **`incidentresolution`***).